# Do you get a roll to resist Sorcery spells in Modiphius' 2d20 Conan game? If so, what kind?

Tags: magic, modiphius-2d20

The rules are rather scattered and unclear with regards to the way Sorcery spells work in this system...it does say that targets of Sorcery get "Courage plus Morale" to SOAK any sorcery damage, but it isn't clear whether they first get a roll to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It Depends on the Spell

The Modiphius sorcery rules are a little opaque, admittedly, but the *Book of Skelos* is supposed to clear them up (as well as add new ones). You have to look at each Spell individually to see how to react to it. Specifically, you should look at the Example Uses of the spells. Most spells assume you will resist them, and so have a resistance written into their text. The text could use some clarification, which I'm sure Modiphius intends to do.

I'll try to break down the Example Use of *Spectral Knife* (A Use of the *Haunt the Mind* Spell) for you. Since magic is somewhat freeform, creating your own Use will require GM interpretation of the rules, so maybe don't do that until you've played the game a while and have a feel for the rules.

The Corebook version of *Spectral Knife* (Corebook pg. 183), for example, is unclear on how to Defend against it, although it does mention that you can:

> By crafting an illusion of a flying shard of steel you can trick a victim into flinching away or otherwise attempting to avoid the blade. A target failing to avoid the blade will take 3 [Damage Dice Icon] damage as if struck. The target will be convinced of the reality of the injury and will later rationalize away the absence of a wound.

But the version from the Conan Quickplay rules (pg. 44) [emphasis mine] makes it explicit how you would counter it. Although, I don't think you should use the Quickplay rules as your reference, since the rules will have changed by the relesase of the corebook, this does illustrates the intent of the 2d20 ruleset in this case:

> Spectral Knife: Costs 2 points of Doom. When cast, Anavenagar may
>   attack one visible enemy in Medium range with an Average (D1) Sorcery
>   test (Willpower plus Knowledge). The target **may attempt a Defense
>   Reaction** as if avoiding a ranged attack. If it hits, the spectral
>   knife deals  4 damage with Vicious 2

This clearly sets a precedent for using Defend Reactions against spells. You'd add points to the Doom Pool just like any other reaction.

### What Do I Roll?

Combat Reactions (Corebook pg 117):

> The character attempts to defend against an attack. This reaction may be used when an enemy attack is attempted and the character has been declared as the target of that attack. This turns the attacker’s skill test into a Struggle. The skill used by the defender is determined by the type of attack, as described in Making an Attack on page 117

To Defend against a Ranged Attack, you'd roll Acrobatics as per the Corebook pg.117.